# React-Redux with Router not updating state in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To briefly explain, I have two components with content that should be updated on window resize. On every window resize we do a history.replace() to a new url and a history.push() back to the old url so that there's a real simulation of change of url. I have created three different situations.

1. Function component: The props (from global state) are always available on every resize and after a url change
2. Class Component (in render): Props (from global state) are also available **in the render method** on every resize and after a url change
3. Class Component (**in componentDidMount**): Props (from global state) not available again after first render and after a url change.

The third scenario is what I'm particular about. I need a way to always update class component after it mounts. Just as it happens for the two above.

I'm trying to wrap my head around what really causes this behavior.

I've written a sample sandbox code to produce what I'm experiencing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/233yq699yr

Comment: I'm not really sure why we're creating a copy of the global state in ComponentDidMount as you're already accessing the global store. Is there a reason why you're not referring to it in your props instead of your copy?

ComponentDidMount() will not fire again until the component is un-mounted and re-mounted again.

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to change the values in the component after every mount. I don't want to always depend on the values from the global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding a componentDidUpdate and comparing props.

Even though this is not so recommended as something like this should only be used in rare cases, this is the only thing that seems to produce the result I was looking for!

https://codesandbox.io/s/233yq699yr

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a cleaner solution. You can remove your `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` code and use a simple function that gives you the flexibility of using `state` or `props`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I also forgot to mention that I'm changing values after every mount and then after every window resize (as shown in the code) which doesn't trigger a re-mount. Rather, redux provides new values from the global store after every resize with which the component needs to update it's state with. So this was obviously the reason for a lack of update in the component's state.

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. In `componentDidMount` you're mutating the `state`directly before even calling `setState`. Also, in `componentDidUpdate` you're checking for equality of two objects which will always return `false`. For example: `{foo: 'bar'} === {foo: 'bar'}` returns `false`. I've updated your sandbox with my proposed changes here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lrryn9nl09

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't be mutating the state directly. Spreading it into a new object resolves that. I also agree that the prevProps and this.props comparison will always return false. But, if we're to keep making use of the componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate methods, that's the only way we'll ever be able to deal with an update. Otherwise we'll get an Update depth exceeded exception. Your solution doesn't go with overriding any of the functions and, though it works and is a nice approach, we might not be able to use it in an application where the values are not initially set to zero.

Comment: For example, if we're getting values other than zero dynamically, the Component will ignore any future changes. Things could become really tricky in bigger applications.

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping your Redux state to `props` already with `mapStateToProps` so you don't need to set it in the component's local `state` with `componentDidMount`. Just use `this.props.dim` in your `render` method:

`{this.props.dim.mobi} => {this.props.dim.editButtonBottom}`

---

> I want to be able to change the values in the component after every mount. I don't want to always depend on the values from the global state.

If you'd like to be able to display a value based on `props` but have the option of overriding that value with `state` then you can do something like this:

```
returnStyleBottom = () => {
    return this.state.style.bottom || this.props.dim.editButtonBottom;
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
        <p>
            Bad (now nice): {this.state.dim.mobi} => {this.returnStyleBottom()}
        </p>
    );
}
```

I've updated your sandbox with this code so you can test it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/lrryn9nl09

By default you have `this.state.style.bottom` set to `0` so the value of `this.props.dim.editButtonBottom` will be used. If you update `this.state.style.bottom` then that will become the displayed value. And if you want to go back to using the value from `props` just set the `state` value back to `0`.

Comment: But I want to always read values from the component's state after every mount because, there I can change values when I want to. I don't want to always depend on global values after each mount.

Comment: @cmdlucas If you set the `state` value once when the component mounts then it won't updated on resize which is already what's happening. Is this what you want? If not can you give some more detail on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: For example, I'd like to get the width of a parent element on every resize. It works on the first page load but doesn't fetch again until the page is explicitly reloaded.

Comment: How is the width of the parent element being passed to this component?